# Is the manual chat is possible in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

Is there any option for manual chat when using dialogflow? My requirement is using both manual and bot.
Kindly suggest which one is good option to fulfill this requirement?

Thankss

Comment: try [kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/)

Comment: have you had a look at https://github.com/dialogflow/agent-human-handoff-nodejs ?